# Angular test 'subscribe is not a function'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, jasmine

In my component inside `ngOnInit` I have a `subscribe()` inside which I call a component function:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.navigationService.itemReset$.subscribe(event => this.resetItem(event));
}
```

in the navigationService I have:

```
btnPressed$: Subject<Event> = new Subject();
itemReset$: Observable<Event> = this.btnPressed$.asObservable();

keyDown(event: Event): void {
  this.btnPressed$.next(event);
}
```

I searched a lot about this issue, and tried something like this in my component test:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let navigationServiceMock = {
    itemReset$: () => of({} as Event),
    // tried this: itemReset$: jasmine.createSpy('itemReset$').and.returnValue(of({})),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      providers: [{
        provide: navigationService,
        useValue: navigationServiceMock
      }]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but still, get the error

```
TypeError: this.navigationService.itemReset$.subscribe is not a function
```

Any idea, why it doesn't work?
I would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the type of `itemReset$` in your fake object matches the type in the implementation.

You need to pass a `Observable<Event>` but you had a function returning such an observable instead.

```js
let navigationServiceMock = {
    itemReset$: of({} as Event),
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You are close but remember you are mocking:

```
let navigationServiceMock = {
    itemReset$: () => of({} as Event),
    // tried this: itemReset$: jasmine.createSpy('itemReset$').and.returnValue(of({})),
  };
```

You have a mocked a function called itemReset$ which returns an observable.

In reality, you want itemReset$ to **be** the observable.

So change your mock to:

```
let navigationServiceMock = {
    itemReset$: of({} as Event),
  };
```

Comment: You have a mocked a function called itemReset$ which returns an observable.

In reality, you want itemReset$ to be the observable. I wasted good time figuring this out.